# What is the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n[\sqrt\frac{4i}{n}]$

Tags: limits, summation

What is the value of $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n[\sqrt\frac{4i}{n}]}$$

Where [x] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to x

Answer is given as $3$ but I think answer will be $3/4$ (by breaking the sum from $1$ to $n/4$ and from $n/4$ to $n$). Please clarify if it is a printing mistake or if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you see a Riemann sum in it?

Comment: This is [x]. Obviously you do not mean a Riemann sum here.

Comment: I do mean a Riemann sum.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Riemann sum. Please solve it.

Comment: If you look again at [the answer to your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846876/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-r-0n-1-cos-fracr/846882#846882), do you see how this fits in?

Comment: In this case, integral will be from $0$ to $1$, function will be probably $\sqrt x$ but I don't know what to do with the box function.

Comment: Not $\sqrt{x}$ but $\left[\sqrt{4x}\right]$.

Comment: Thats fine, but can't we do it in a simpler way by breaking the sum from 1 to n/4 and from n/4 to n.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. If you do that, you have the minor annoyance of distinguishing between the cases where $n$ is a multiple of $4$ and where it isn't, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know whether 3/4 was the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing but the evaluation of the integral $$\int_0^1\sqrt{[4x]} dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} 0dx+\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^1 dx=\frac{3}{4}$$